# ROS-plugin for QT Creator

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure wether this is the right place for this question, but I don't really know where else I might find an answer for this.

The thing is, I'm on my roscpp code in QT Creator. I found out, there is a ROS-plugin for this IDE, but on the Computers that I'm working on, I don't have admin rights and therefor can't install the plugin as described [here](https://ros-qtc-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html). Is there any way to install this plugin on linux without being able to use sudo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318935/ros-plugin-for-qt-creator/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> on the Computers that I'm working on, I don't have admin rights and therefor can't install the plugin as described [here](https://ros-qtc-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html). Is there any way to install this plugin on linux without being able to use sudo?

Can you clarify where in those instructions you believe you should use `sudo`?

The plugin comes with a Qt Creator installation and places everything in your `$HOME` directory, so `sudo` should not be needed.

It's only used in those instructions to remove something, but only then if you had that on your system in the first place:

> If previously installed using the ppa please follow the procedure below to remove old version

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2019-03-20**:
My bad, I'm sorry. You are right, sudo isn't necessary